# Zend/PHP: how to perform HTTP POST to controller and mapper php classes

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, zend-framework

Our Android app should perform a POST request to a server running PHP Zend in order to save data in MySQL. Our boss told us to implement the following class, according to Zend MVC:

**GcmUsersController.php**

```
class GcmUsersController extends AppController
{
 public function registationAction()
  {
   if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
      $token = $this->getRequest()->getPost('token');
      $android_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('android_id');
      $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
      $gcm = new Application_Model_GcmUsersMapper();
      $info = array(
          "tokenid" => $token,
          "gcm_regid" => $android_id,
          "name" => $name,
          "email" => "a@a.it"
      );
      $gcm->insert2($info, "GcmUsers");
   }
}
?>
```

**GcmUsersMapper.php**

```
class Application_Model_GcmUsersMapper extends Application_Model_AppMapper
{

  protected $_mvcTable = 'GcmUsers';

  protected $_dbTable = 'gcm_users';
}
```

Which is the url to which our app Android should perform the POST HTTP? That's what we did:

```
final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mypath/GcmUsers/registration");
```

because we thought there was a bind between registration in the URL and registration action in the controller but it does not work. Which is the correct way?

Comment: Your url should contain the php script file. So `GcmUsersController.php`.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION** is this:

inside views->scripts create directory `apnsdevices` and insert into this the file `registrationapple.phtml` which is:

```
<?php 
  echo $this->data;
?>
```

Then, this is `ApnsDevicesMapper.php`

```
<?php 
class Application_Model_ApnsDevicesMapper extends Application_Model_AppMapper
{

protected $_mvcTable = 'ApnsDevices';

protected $_dbTable = 'apns_devices';

public function registration($device_id, $token) {
    $where = "deviceuid = '".$device_id."'";
    $c = $this->count($this->_mvcTable,$this->_dbTable,$where);
    if($c == 0){
        $info = array(
            "devicetoken" => $token,
            "deviceuid" => $device_id
        );
        $this->insert2($info, "ApnsDevices");

    }
    return $c;   
}


}
?>
```

and this is `ApnsdevicesController.php`

```
<?php
class ApnsdevicesController extends AppController
{
public function registrationappleAction()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        $token = $this->getRequest()->getPost('token');
        $device_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('device_id');
        $apns = new Application_Model_ApnsDevicesMapper();
        $c = $apns->registration($device_id, $token);
        $this->view->data = $c;
    }
}

}

?>
```

Finally, I can perform the POST method to the following URL:

`http://server_path/apnsdevices/registrationapple`